# Java editor for Chrome OS

Tags: java, text-editor, chrome-os

I'm a student in Sweden studying programming and recently we got Chromebooks to make it easier to study and write essays. I realized soon that I wasn't able to install any software to my Chromebook so I started searching for some online Java editors where I could easily sit down and continue to edit the code I last wrote from my PC at home (Eclipse).

Do you have any proposals on good Java editors?

I've tried a couple of editors but they were not good enough for my standards. Most of the editors lacked propper syntax checking (caret).